# Avoiding support bash functions to show up in terminal sessions when tab-completing

Tags: bash, autocomplete, function

I have a number of `bash` functions which I source from my `.bashrc`.  I also have a bunch of support function that are needed but do not want them to show up in a terminal session when a user does tab-completion.

My `bash` functions start with `xepty-`.  Support functions also start with `xepty-`.  Thus when users are in a terminal window, and they input `xepty-`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, they get a large number of matches.  Is it possible to make the support functions unavailable for use in the terminal session?

Comment: `.bashrc` is the initialization file for interactive sessions. Why are the functions there if you don't want to use them in interactive sessions? Are they just supposed to be used internally to `.bashrc` itself?

Comment: It would be simpler to rename the support functions, e.g. as `_xepty-`  and leave the functions that are expected to be used interactively as `xepty-`.

Comment: Yes, there are many which would be of no interest to the user, but are used internally by the functions that users would actually use.

Comment: How is it that the functions that you define in your user `.bashrc` end up in other users interactive shells? You do need to split "personal" scripts from "system" scripts.

Comment: Many want to use them, so they source them from their `.bashrc`, but the support functions won't be useful for them to run.

Comment: Apart from using a different name like _xepty- can one actually stop them from being accessed by terminal shell?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html for details. In order to make this maintainable you will probably want to invent a variable like `FIGNORE` to tell it which functions you want it to ignore rather than coding them into the completion function. I repeat my advice to be pragmatic and just mark the functions that are not intended to be used directly by the user by starting their name with an `_` or some other marker. If this does not suffice then please explain the use case in detail.

Comment: I agree with marking with a starting `_`.  Regarding `export`, I would need to export all functions (including those marked with `_`) used by the tool I want users to access, right?

Comment: Should I make an additional function that exports the functions I need in the same file.  Or gather the export functions together in a separate file?